# How to import modules for testing?

Tags: haskell, testing, import, project

I am trying to test some functions using QuickCheck for my Haskell project. My directory currently looks like this:

```
|-cswk2
  |-validCard.hs //THIS FILE CONTAINS MY HASKELL FUNCTIONS 
  |-tests
    |-testSuite.hs //THIS FILE CONTAINS MY QUICKCHECK FUNCTIONS
```

Inside my Haskell file i have some functions that i want to test, this looks something like this...

validCard.hs:

```
module Cswk2 where

getCard :: Integer -> [Integer]
...
```

...while my test file looks like this.

testSuite.hs:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.HUnit
import Cswk2

prop_numb :: [Integer] -> Bool
...
```

Unfortunately, i keep getting an error saying 'Failed to load interface for Cswk2' and was wondering if it was a problem with the way i have structured my directory for testing. I initially tried using cabal and following the user manual to setup a test suite but that lead to many more problems than this and left me more confused. I am new to Haskell so if anyone could highlight what exactly i am doing wrong and advise me on ways to structure a project for testing that would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: How are you building these files exactly? I mean, share the exact command you type in order to build.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin to run the test i was trying to load the testSuit.hs into ghci and run the test through there. Not sure if its correct but that's how i've used quickCheck before

Comment: Can you please share the exact sequence of commands?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin `ghci testSuite.hs` then i would plan to run `quickCheck prop_numb`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, most people who write Haskell code with any degree of complexity use a build system. The community seems to be roughly evenly split between [Stack](https://haskellstack.org) and [Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal).

In both cases, the most common way to organise code is to keep separate directories for production and test code:

```
|-cswk2
  |-src
    |-validCard.hs //THIS FILE CONTAINS MY HASKELL FUNCTIONS 
  |-tests
    |-testSuite.hs //THIS FILE CONTAINS MY QUICKCHECK FUNCTIONS
```

With the build systems, you're also going to need a file that defines dependencies. That'll typically be a `.cabal` or `package.yaml` file.

I have various examples of code bases that use Stack on GitHub. Here's one of intermediate complexity: https://github.com/ploeh/reservation-api-slice-haskell

Comment: I've taken a look at Stack to build my system and so far making better progress than i did with Cabal using your links and some others. Hopefully once i come up with a clearer understanding i can share my findings on the post

Comment: When using stack to organise your build, if you want to run your Main.hs how would you create an executable? `ghc Main.hs` gives me the same 'Failed to load interface' error

Comment: @CadyOG With Stack, you don’t use `ghc` directly. To compile, you run `stack build`.